# Is the following sequence increasing strictly? If it converges, why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

$$x_{n+1} = 3x_n^2+\frac{1}{12}$$
With initial starting value $x_0=0$

If it converges I can just substitute $x$ with $A$ and solve for $A$ to calculate the limit, right?

Comment: Please take the time to learn the basics of MathJax and $\LaTeX$.  See an introduction [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Many times, this just means placing dollar signs around what you want to type and type it very similarly to how you would with ascii.  There is no reason to have such a low quality image to represent so few characters.

Comment: As for your question... This depends on what the initial value of $x_0$ is which you neglected to include in your picture or post.  If you can show that the sequence is *monotone* (*e.g. increasing*) and that the sequence is *bounded*, then you can apply the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) and conclude that it does in fact converge.  Once you know that it does in fact converge, then yes... one method of finding what it converges *to* is as you describe, replacing both $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ with the same variable, such as $A$, and solving

Comment: Questions need to be improved when posting to such forums. Give more details and the procedure you follow.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify the value of $x_0$

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the starting point.
If $x_1 > x_0$, then you can show by induction that $x_{n+1} > x_n$.  But in that case it won't converge.

Answer (score 0):

First send complete question.
What is the initial value $x_0$?
Put $x_{n+1}=x_n=A$.Then solve the equation. Which point is convergent point depend on the nature of the sequence. This is the method of this sort of problems.